# Do I need a [MyFiles] header for each path entry?

Tags: samba, sharing

I want to share two folders on my Ubuntu box for my W7 machine to use. I typed `[MyFiles]` only once, then a separate block entry for each path. When I testparmed, only the last path was shown.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about Samba, given you've mentioned the `testparm` utility.

The section headers in the `smb.conf` file represent the different shares Samba will provide.  So if you've added a `[MyFiles]` section, then Samba will share it as `\\hostname\MyFiles` to Windows machines.

Each share serves the files from a single folder, so if you want to share two different folders you will need to configure two shares in the `smb.conf` file (with different section names).